# I want to create an object within a looping statement. Is such a dynamic creation possible in java?

Tags: java, loops, object, dynamic

I want to create an object within a loop. I do not know how many iterations take place. At each iteration I need to create a new object and the object created at previous iteration should be accessible even outside the loop. Is this possible?

For instance there is a global variable 'a' of 'int' type.

Inside the loop I want object created such that at 1st iteration
object1.a = 0;
At 2nd iteration
object2.a = 1;
At 3rd iteration
object3.a = 2;

And so on, till n unknown iterations.
I want to be able to access each of these object1, object2,.... later in the code. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe Create a List of Objects before starting the loop.

   ```
   List<Object> list=new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. And inside the Loop create a new object and add it to the list.

   ```
   list.add(new Object);
   ```
3. After Completion of the Loop, maybe you can iterate over the list and fetch the objects.

Comment: Will try  Thanks for the response